# Is it possible to execute code in SQL Server when a user aborts a procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssms

I currently have an audit process that is part of all procedures and it is very basic at a high level.

- Procedure is executed.
- It inserts into the Audit table with a start time and status of Running.
- It completes with out errors and then updates that record to show a status of Complete.
- If there is an actual error it will update with a status of Error.

However if a user manually aborts the procedures via the SQL Server Management Studio no update will occur. The record will remain as "Running".

Is there any functionality I can use to capture this scenario so I can tie out the audit record?

Comment: Are the inserts and updates in the same proc? You need a transaction to guarantee all-or-none since no code will execute if the user cancels the query (or the server crashes, etc.).

Comment: I currently do not use BEGIN TRANS anywhere. (New to SQL Server coming from TD/Oracle). Currently I have each component wrapped in TRY/CATCH. Should I be adding BEGIN TRANS? It is all contained in one stored procedure.

Comment: An BEGIN TRAN/COMMIT in the TRY block and ROLLBACK in the catch will ensure all-or-none. Also, add `SET XACT_ABORT ON`  to ensure the transaction is rolled back immediately if the query is cancelled.

Comment: In Oracle and Postgres stored procedures automatically create transactions.  In SQL Server you need to explicitly create transactions in your stored procedures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to enclose it inside a transaction, and use `XACT_ABORT` for automatic rollback.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE YourProc
  -- parameters here
AS

SET NOCOUNT, XACT_ABORT ON;

BEGIN TRAN;

-- everything else here

COMMIT;
```

*Always* use `SET XACT_ABORT ON` if you have a transaction. This ensures that if the code is aborted or it errors, the transaction will be rolled back and not left hanging.

Do not use `TRY CATCH` unless you want to actually handle the error and log it. It is not necessary to use `CATCH` to ensure a rollback if you have `XACT_ABORT`. If you do catch, then rethrow the error using `THROW;` rather than `RAISERROR`. For example:

```sql
BEGIN CATCH
    IF XACT_STATE() <> 0
        ROLLBACK;

    INSERT Audit... ;

    THROW;
END CATCH;
```

But note that certain errors cannot be caught, and a user abort cannot be caught either. I suggest you use XEvents for that .

Comment: So in this example how would you add a TRY/CATCH -- also if I wanted to write an INSERT into an (example: dbo.AUDIT) table on the start of the proc, and then update that line on either user abort or an error how would I do so?

Comment: You could do it in a `CATCH` for example `BEGIN CATCH IF XACT_STATE() <> 0 ROLLBACK; INSERT Audit... ; THROW; END CATCH;` but note that certain errors cannot be caught, and a user abort cannot be caught either. I suggest you use XEvents for that